# Using AuthenticationStateProvider in C# class instead of .razor page

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, httpcontext

I have a web application that uses Oauth 2.0 authorization to login.
Getting the claims from AuthenticationStateProvider in a Blazor page is pretty simple:

```
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthState

@code
{
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        authenticationState = await AuthState.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        username = authenticationState.User.FindFirst("claim type name here");
    }
}
```

Then I can display the username easily in the .razor document HTML part.
However, I want to get this username and use it when calling an API on behalf of that username. I just can't understand how to use the AuthenticationStateProvider and inject the stuff I need in a normal C# class that's not a blazor page.

I found a solution for getting the claims from HttpContext and it's like this:

```
public class UserIdentity
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public UserIdentity(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
       this._httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string GetUsername()
    {
        var username = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        return username;
    }
}
```

But I don't understand how to use that class with the constructor elsewhere. I would have to pass a IHttpContextAccessor when creating an instance of the class and I can't make sense of it.

EDIT: Changed some of this and tried a new approach:

```
public class UserIdentity
{
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;

    public UserIdentity(AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider)
    {
       this._authenticationStateProvider = _authenticationStateProvider;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetUsername()
    {
        var authstate = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        System.Security.Claims.Claim username = authstate.User.FindFirst("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier");
        return username.Value;
    }
}
```

Returns null reference exception. But the real problem is I don't know how to use the UserIdentity. I don't see the point of constructor injection when I have to pass a value.

```
UserIdentity identity = new UserIdentity(... AuthenticationStateProvider? ...);
```